# Assign media item to sitecore item using powershell script

Tags: powershell-extensions, media-library

I want to add an image to an item using powershell script and here is my code. I don't know what i'm missing..

```
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()

[Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField]$fieldValueLink = $Item.Fields[$templateField.DisplayName]
$fieldValueLink.Width = 1324
$fieldValueLink.Height = 577
$fieldValueLink.Alt="Image"
$fieldValueLink.Value = $itemRow.$fieldTrimmedValue
$item[$templateField.DisplayName] = $itemRow.$fieldTrimmedValue;

$item.Editing.EndEdit() | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 4):

**Example:** The following shows how to retrieve an image from the media library and assign it to the image field on a content item.

```
$homeItem = Get-Item -Path "master:/content/home"
$homeItem.Image = Get-Item -Path "master:\media library\logo"
$homeItem.PSFields.Image.Alt = "I like turtles"
```

**Example:** The following shows both editing mode and automatic properties:

```
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()   

# Whatever other fields you want...
$item[$templateField.Name]= Get-Item -Path "master:\media library\auto-email"

$item.Editing.EndEdit() | Out-Null    

# This notation does not require the Begin/End edit calls.
$item.PSFields.Image.Alt = "I like turtles"
```

#### Resources

- https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items

Comment: $item[$templateField.Name] = Get-Item -Path "master:\media library\auto-email";
$item[$templateField.PSFields.Image.Alt] = "GoogleLogo";      $item.Editing.EndEdit() | Out-Null                                        
 on adding this code getting the following error                                                
 Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
              $item[$templateField.PSFields.Image.Alt] = "GoogleLogo";

Comment: My example automatically puts the item in editing mode whenever it modifies the field. I'll make an update to follow your example.

Comment: I am getting this error. The property 'Image' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.